# Dynamically Build Include with Where Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

## Background

I need to be able to build a .Include that filters results down to records created on or before a specific date. I will not know the types of the objects on the original LINQ statement, and I will be finding them (through a whole lot of hoops, but that is working).

I have a graph of objects like this:

```
          A -> Ac
         /  \
  Bc <- B    \
       /      \  
Cc <- C        D -> Dc
```

Objects `Ac`, `Bc`, `Cc`, and `Dc` are all found dynamically (that is, a developer does not type in these relationships when writing the original linq statement). These then need to be added to an IQueryable expression and only return values up to a specific DateTime.

## The Code So Far

I tried building a function that constructs a lambda and compares dates. So far, if the original query is `A.Include(x => x.B).Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.C)`, I can construct the string `"A.B.Bc"`, so I know the types of A, B, and Bc, and the way they relate.

```
private static IQueryable<T> FilterChangeTrackerToDate<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string includeString, DateTime targetDateTime)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ), "x" );

    var prop = Expression.Property(param, includeString + ".CreatedUtc");

    var dateConst = Expression.Constant(targetDateTime);

    var compare = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(prop, dateConst);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(compare, param);

    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

The issue is that the above code crashes because `"A.B.Bc.CreatedUtc"` isn't the correct way to load the date property - I need to traverse this through `.Select` statements.

## The Problem

In order to both *load* the records and *filter* them, I need to dynamically build a `.Select` to pull out the values I need (which, thankfully, are static based on inheritance) and put those values into an anonymous type, which can then be filtered with a `.Where()`. All of this needs to be done with minimal generics, as I don't have compile-time types to validate against and I'd have to abuse reflection to get them to work.

Essentially, I need to create this:

```
.Select( x => new
{
    Bc = x.B.Select(z => z.Bc.Select(y => y.CreatedUtc).Where( q => q > DateTime.UtcNow ) ),
    A= x
} )
```

dynamically, using the string "A.B.Bc", for any level of nesting.

## Resources

This is where I saw how to filter an EF include method:
[LINQ To Entities Include + Where Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386501/linq-to-entities-include-where-method#19386600)

This post talks about dynamically creating a Select, but it is only selecting top-level values and does not seem like it can build the rest of the parts needed for my problem: [How to create LINQ Expression Tree to select an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-to-select-an-anonymous-type#723018)

## Dynamic Linq

Using the System.Linq.Dynamic library, I have tried to access the `CreatedUtc` value off of Bc:

```
query = (IQueryable<T>) query.Select(includeString + ".CreatedUtc");
```

Where `includeString = "B.Bc"`, but this gives me an exception of:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: No property or field 'Bc' exists in type 'List`1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `System.Linq.Dynamic` is what you need. It's a library originally written by ScottGu from Microsoft, and it allows you to build LINQ query from string like that:

```
IQueryable nestedQuery = query.Select("B.Bc.CreatedUtc");
```

where query is `IQueryable<A>`.

There is a number of forks of this library. You can start from [here](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic). Documentation on query language is [here](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions). Also [here](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) there is a version with some additional functionality and [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) is dotnet.core version.

**UPD1:**
[This](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) library lacks of SelectMany extension method but [this](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) one has. So with latter library you can do the following:

```
query.SelectMany("B").SelectMany("Bc").Select("CreatedUtc");
```

Comment: When I include the string `"B.Bc.CreatedUtc"`, I get this error: `Additional information: No property or field 'Bc' exists in type 'List`1'`. It doesn't look like it's exploring nested graphs correctly?

Comment: Yeah, all of my foreign key relationships are collections for this purpose - though they may be 1-1 in the future, so ideally the solution would be able to accommodate both.

Comment: @Max have you included them? (`.Include(...)`)

Comment: @Max you have to tell EF to load your dependencies, or they will not be accessable.

Comment: If you mean on the incoming original IQueryable, then B is `Include`d but Bc is not.

Comment: @Max then thats why the error is "No property or field 'Bc' exists"

Comment: That means that the dynamic library explores objects in a query and not the objects themselves, right? If it can't create the `.Select()` because I didn't `.Include()` an object, that means it can only find objects that are already in the query.